# Grouping csv file based on column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I have a file with each row  having specific data

[image]

expected output is

[image]

- condition 1 : where ever source is 'a' need to rename its headers with prefix 'seed_'
- condition 2 : can make use of bundle id for group

Any way is it doable from pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing to split your dataframe (group 'a' vs other) then use `merge`:

```
m = df['source'] == 'a'
out = df[m].drop(columns='source').merge(df[~m], on='bundle id', suffixes=('_seed', '_comp'))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  name_seed  bundle id  price_seed  name_comp  price_comp source
0    iphone        123         999  iphone 12         950      b
1    iphone        123         999  iphone 13         975      c
2     apple        345         100    Apple 1          99      c
```